# Why am I getting the wrong milliseconds for a given string time?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
Date d = null;

try {
    d = df1.parse("21:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm getting 61200000 milliseconds but when I convert it online, I get a different value.

Comment: `Constructs a SimpleDateFormat using the default pattern and date format symbols for the default locale. ` May be you locale is different from the server

Comment: @VGR when i was priniting i was doing "d.getTime()" and this was giving me 61200000... but if i only print "d" i get :  Thu Jan 01 21:00:00 GMT +04:00 1970 ...what does that mean and how can i fix that?

Comment: @TamilSelvanC im new to all that.. can u give me an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat` is not so simple as the name suggests. In particular its handling of time zone is sometimes obscure. In this case I dare say it uses your JVM’s time zone setting (probably taken over from your computer’s setting), apparently one that is offset 4 hours from UTC. So when the time is 21:00 (9 pm) in your time zone, it’s 17:00 in UTC. The milliseconds value in a `Date` object is always in UTC, therefore you get 17 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 61 200 000. If you try it online on a server in a different time zone, you’re likely to get a different result.

## `java.time.Duration`

I think what you really want is [`Duration.parse("PT21H0M")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-). This will give you a duration of 21 hours 0 minutes. You can use its [`toMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toMillis--) method to get 21 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 75 600 000.

The Java 8 date and time classes (of which `Duration` is just one) are generally much more pleasant to work with than the old classes.

Or you can [pass a number of hours](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#ofHours-long-).

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 21 );
```

## ISO 8601 duration

The syntax `PT21H0M` may look a bit odd at first, but its an international standard, [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), so we’d probably better learn to work with it, and it’s straightforward to learn.

Comment: Duration.parse(...) is not recognised?! what should i do?

Comment: Is `Duration` not recognized, or `parse()`? The class `java.time.Duration` was introduced in Java 8, so you need at least this version. As with almost all classes you need to `import` it.

Answer (score -1):

If you do this:

```
d = df1.parse("21:00");
```

you get this date

```
Thu Jan 01 21:00:00 CET 1970
```

and the epoch is 72000000, to convert that, you need to divide by 1000

verifiable [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: When i tried parsing "21:00", i get Thu Jan 01 21:00:00 GMT +04:00 1970